# How to store and access previous sites accessed in WebView

Tags: ios, webview, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have a simple app with a few navigation buttons that load pre-defined websites within a webview container.

If possible I would like the user to back to the last URL they visited after they click a different button.

E.g. User clicks button 1 and goes to google.com, carry's out a search. User then clicks button 2 and reads some posts on stackoverflow, they then decide to go back to button 1 (google). In an ideal world the user would see the search results that they carried out on button 1, and not be directed back to google.com

Would I  be able to use getURL to store the last visited URL, and then reload that URL once the user goes back to that button? If so how would I go about storing the URL? I am quite new to Titanium.

I also have another version of the app that uses a tab group and loads different webviews into each tab, which solves the problem of loading the last URL but makes the app memory heavy as it uses a lot of webviews.

Comment: Maybe you can use the tiBrowser module to solve your problem : https://github.com/jdanthinne/tiBrowser ?

Comment: Thank you, how would this module help with going back to the last visited URL? I want the users to have back/forwards navigation but not a navigation bar or title bar

Comment: As you can see in the Readme, this widget create a Webview with Back/forward button, refresh and options button. You can, customize it to remove the navigation bar if you want.

Comment: I see thank you, but it doesn't address the issue of saving the last url as far as I can see?

Answer (score 3):

Try look at this[Ti WebView 'load' event listener](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.WebView-event-load).

- You can use load event to know which url is currently being shown in the webview.
- In order to have a navigation system, save all urls in an array.
- To perform back and forth operations, use variables to keep track whether the user has pressed back button or forward button.

Try above steps and till then we will try to put some demo code for you. :)

Thanks

Comment: Thank you, I think I have something basic working: webview5.addEventListener('beforeload', function(findCurrentURL) { alert(findCurrentURL.url); }); However I'm not to sure on how to go about saving them as an array...sorry very basic question I'm sure!

Answer (score 2):

tiBrowser widget https://github.com/jdanthinne/tiBrowser doesn't expose a method to get the last url. But you can easily add it, into widget.js https://github.com/jdanthinne/tiBrowser/blob/master/be.grincheux.tiBrowser/controllers/widget.js add this :

```
function getHistory(){

  return history;

}

exports.getHistory = getHistory;
```

`history` is an array that contains all the address visited.

Comment: Thank you that looks very useful, I will take a look into it and see if I can get it working!